# Expectation and variance of product of sine and cosine of normally distributed random variables.

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, statistics, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Given $X$~$N(0,\sigma^2_X)$ and $Y$~$N(0,\sigma^2_Y)$ ($X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed random variables with expectations given by $\mu_X=\mu_Y=0$ and variances given by $\sigma^2_X$ and $\sigma^2_Y)$, can anyone help me figure out the expectation and variance of $Z=\sin(X)\cos(Y)$?

NOTE: $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I have found some threads that purport the following:

$E[\cos(X)]=e^{-\sigma^2_X/2}$

$E[\sin(X)]=0$

but i still have trouble using this info to deduce $Z=\sin(X)\cos(Y)$

I just realized the answer is zero. Ayyyyye

### ***EDIT:***

I am also curious to know...

$E[\sin X \cos X]$

where $X$~$N(0,\sigma)$. Here, the domain of $X$ is any real number, but any such number actually corresponds to an angle in radians.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? Can you work out the expectation and variance of just $\sin(X)$ (or $\cos(Y)$) alone first?

Comment: Yes they are independent. see update to post. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies $$\operatorname{E}[Z] = \operatorname{E}[\sin X] \operatorname{E}[\cos Y] = 0,$$ as you already observed.

The variance is more complicated.  You'd need to compute $$\operatorname{Var}[Z] = \operatorname{E}[Z^2] - \operatorname{E}[Z]^2 = \operatorname{E}[Z^2] = \operatorname{E}[\sin^2 X \cos^2 Y] = \operatorname{E}[\sin^2 X] \operatorname{E}[\cos^2 Y].$$

To this end, recall that $$\cos^2 \theta = \frac{1 + \cos 2\theta}{2}, \quad \sin^2 \theta = \frac{1 - \cos 2\theta}{2}.$$  So for instance, $$\operatorname{E}[\sin^2 X] = \frac{1 - \operatorname{E}[\cos 2X]}{2} = \frac{1 - e^{-2\sigma_X^2}}{2},$$ since $2X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0, 4 \sigma_X^2)$.  A similar result holds for $\operatorname{E}[\cos^2 Y]$.

All that is left is to demonstrate that $\operatorname{E}[\cos X] = e^{-\sigma_X^2/2}$, which you state without proof.  (The fact that $\operatorname{E}[\sin X] = 0$ is an immediate consequence of the fact that $|\sin X| \le 1$ and $\sin (-X) = -\sin X$.)  I recommend that you try this as an exercise.

Comment: can you provide insight on $E[\sin X \cos X]$ ?

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy It is zero for the same reason that $\operatorname{E}[\sin X] = 0$:  because $\sin (-X) \cos (-X) = -\sin X \cos X$.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the edit, note that $Z = \sin X \cos X = g(X)$ is a function $g$ of the normal random variable $X$~$N(0,\sigma)$ whose pdf is given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-1}{2} x^2\sigma^{-2}}$. By definition of the expectation of a continuous random variable, we have

$\mathbb{E} \big[ Z ] = \mathbb{E} \big[ \sin X \cos X ]  = \mathbb{E} \big[ g(X) ] = {\huge\int}_0^{2\pi} g(x) f(x) dx = {\huge\int}_0^{2\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx$

Let us parse the integral as follows

$= {\huge\int}_0^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx + {\huge\int}_{\pi}^{2\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx $

Now consider that $\sin x = \sin (x-2\pi)$ and $\cos x = \cos (x-2\pi)$. Hence, we may rewrite the second integral as follows

$= {\huge\int}_0^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx + {\huge\int}_{\pi}^{2\pi} \sin (x-2\pi) \cos (x-2\pi) f(x) dx $

Now, we shift the limits of the second integral using this helpul identity $\int_a^b h(x) dx = \int_{a+c}^{b+c} h(x-c) dx = \int_{a-c}^{b-c} h(x+c) dx$ so that we have

$= {\huge\int}_0^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx + {\huge\int}_{\pi-2\pi}^{2\pi-2\pi} \sin (x-2\pi+2\pi) \cos (x-2\pi+2\pi) f(x+2\pi) dx $

$= {\huge\int}_0^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx + {\huge\int}_{-\pi}^{0} \sin x \cos x f(x+2\pi) dx $

$= {\huge\int}_0^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx + {\huge\int}_{0}^{\pi} \sin (-x) \cos (-x) f(-x-2\pi) dx $

$= {\huge\int}_0^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx + {\huge\int}_{0}^{\pi} \sin (-x) \cos x f(-x-2\pi) dx $

$= {\huge\int}_0^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx - {\huge\int}_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(-x-2\pi) dx $

Note that $f(-x-2\pi) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-1}{2} (-x-2\pi)^2\sigma^{-2}} = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-1}{2} \big[-1(x+2\pi)\big]^2\sigma^{-2}} = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-1}{2} (x+2\pi)^2\sigma^{-2}} = f(x + 2\pi)$, so we have

$= {\huge\int}_0^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx - {\huge\int}_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x+2\pi) dx $

In applications where the pdf $f$ describes a [wrapped probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_distribution), that is, a distribution corresponding to data values that lie along a unit circle, then we have $f(y) = f(y \mod 2\pi)$. If we let $y = x + 2\pi$, then $y \mod 2\pi = (x + 2\pi) \mod 2\pi = x$ where $x \in [0,\pi]$. Thus, $f(y) = f(x + 2\pi) = f(y \mod 2\pi) = f(x)$ and the result is

$= {\huge\int}_0^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx - {\huge\int}_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \cos x f(x) dx = 0$

So in summary, $\mathbb{E} \big[ \sin X \cos X ] = 0$